# What does KeyListener do exactly?

Tags: android, keylistener

If I'm right, there is a bug that when the locale says the decimal point is comma (as in Germany or Italy), Android's numeric keyboad does not accept entering commas. It still only accetps dots. I must fix this bug in my app. Requirements are:

1. When focus is set to an EditText, the program brings up the soft keyboard in symbol/numeric mode.
2. When under European locales, the keyboard accepts a comma (and a sign).
3. And, #2 must be done programmatically.

I find that I can use XML to achieve #1 and #2 (althgout it'd allow mutiple signs and decimal points in the intput), but it doesn't satisfy #3:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
android:digits="1234567890,-"
```

Documentation says `android:digits` can be acheieved by using `KeyListener`. So I did a KeyListener to allow/disallow characters. But from what I saw, no matter what I return from `onKeyDown()`, the input character is always allowed. I expect KeyListener() allows me to filter the input, but I must have missed something. Could you please point it out? Thank you!

```
et.setKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override public void clearMetaKeyState(View view, Editable content, int states) {} 
    @Override public int getInputType() {  return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER; }
    @Override public boolean onKeyDown(View view, Editable text, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode >= KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0 && keyCode <= KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9) ||
            keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MINUS || 
            keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_COMMA) {
            // I want to allow these
            return false;
        }
        // I want to disallow the rest
        return true;
    }
    @Override public boolean onKeyOther(View view, Editable text, KeyEvent event) { return false; }
    @Override public boolean onKeyUp(View view, Editable text, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { return false; }
});
```

P.S: I've also tried to use `et.setFilters()` and give it a custom `InputFilter`. But it seems that as long as `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` exists, which I need to set keyboard to number/symbol mode, it ignores my filter.

```
final int decimalPoint = ',';
InputFilter[] filterArray = new InputFilter[1];  
filterArray[0] = new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) 
    {
        int dots = 0, i;
        String s = source.toString();
        String d = dest.toString();
        boolean hasSign = false;

        if (source.length() == 0)
            return null;

        for (i = 0; i < d.length(); i++)
            if (d.charAt(i) == '-')
                hasSign = true;
            else if (d.charAt(i) == decimalPoint)
                dots++;
        for (i = start; i < end && i < s.length(); i++) {
            if ((s.charAt(i) >= '0' && s.charAt(i) <= '9') ||
                (s.charAt(i) == '-' && !hasSign && i == start && d.length() == 0))
                continue;
            if (s.charAt(i) == decimalPoint && dots == 0) {
                dots++;
                continue;
            }
            s = s.substring(0, start) + s.substring(start + 1, end);
            end--;
        }
        return s.length() == source.length() ? null : s;
    }};
et.setFilters(filterArray);
```

Comment: Without a Keylistener it works for me. The XML File for the edit:  <EditText android:digits="1234567890,.-" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText1"
  android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned">
  <requestFocus></requestFocus>
 </EditText>

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
et.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("1234567890,-"));
```

Comment: Does work for the default keyboard. But the default keyboard of Samsung devices (tested with S3 running 4.3) failes to show the decimal seperator after adding this listener (also with "1234567890.,-")

Answer (score -2):

Everything you need to know about KeyListener is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/KeyListener.html)

Hope that assists you.